# How can I get a row count all replicated tables in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, replication

I am trying to build a report which would show the row counts of replicated tables on the subscriber and publisher?
Please help..thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You enumerate the publications with [`sp_helppublication`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189782%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx).
2. You enumerate the articles in a publication with [`sp_helparticle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187741%28v=SQL.105%29.aspx)
3. You find the base object for each published article
4. You count the rows in the base objects (from step 3)
5. You find the destination object of each article
6. You list the subscribers with [`sp_helpsubscription`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190493.aspx)
7. On each subscriber, you count the rows in the destination objects (from step 3)

Comment: Is there any way I can query system tables/views and get this information from the distributor? We have a central distributor and multiple publishers and a single subscriber.

Comment: The distributor doesn't have the info you need. It only has the deltas, changes that have to be applied to subscribers. Instead you can, in theory, figure out on the distributor if it has any pending change for any subscriber (meaning that subscriber *must* be behind), and you can also figure out if the distributor is lagging behind the publisher (so *all* subscribers are behind). The tables of interest are `MSrepl_commands` and `MSrepl_transactions`, search MSDN.